# How to change color of google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I found something how to customize my googlemap [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/ref_mapoptions.asp) - but what I didnt find is -> you know for example option ROADMAP. here is map , on this mop is many colors like green, yellow etc.  it is possible to make this map black and white or in Grayscale? Thanks

Comment: before posting your question you can do a basic grammar and spelling review, it won't hurt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here example for set style to map of google map with google Map API :), I hope this help
URL:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

```
var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

Comment: Dont worry .. of course :-) ... It takes 5 minutes I can do that